# Hiding an animated modal UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, animation

I need to present and then dismiss a UITableView modally. It should animate in from top to button. But it should not cover the whole screen, it will slide in from under navigation bar and stop before it reaches the tabbar.

So i can't use the `presentViewController:animated:completion:` for its view controller. 
I need to manipulate it as part of a view hierarchy. The question is, where should this table view be when it is not visible. Where will I animate it from?

Answer (score 1):

You could put the UITableView inside a UIView and use animateWithDuration.  For example (using some made up dimensions):

```
[subMenuView setFrame:CGRectMake(5,-400, 310, 400)];

[UIView animateWithDuration:0.8f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionTransitionCurlDown
                 animations:^{
                     [subMenuView setFrame:CGRectMake(5,0,310,400)];
                 }
                 completion:^ (BOOL finished) 
                 {
                     if (finished) 
                     {
                         //animation has finished, you can do something here, even another nested animation
                     }
                 }];
```

If you want to then slide it back up, do the opposite...

Comment: UITableView inherits from UIView, so I would guess, it can animate on its own. Ceteris paribus no need for embedding it in other view.
My concern is more about hiding it in some negative dimension. I feel like there should be a better way :-/

Comment: You are correct that you don't need the UIView, was thinking more for organization purposes, but as for hiding it in a negative dimension, this is typically the way.  You can always bring it to a negative dimension then straight up hide it.  I do not know of a better way of hiding something other than a. setHidden b. negative dimension